# How do you increment an Int by 1 at position X in a URL String using Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, web-scraping, scrape

What is the best way to increment an Int by 1 at position X in a String. 
For example, if I am trying to web scrape hundreds of URL's all containing a single number, how do you increment from a root url to a higher value.

- www.scrapeme1.com  (Root URL)
- www.scrapeme2.com
- ...
- .....
- www.scrapeme150.com

Please see my best code attempt below.

```
 static final Pattern NUMBER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\d+");

 static String increment(String s) {
     Matcher m = NUMBER_PATTERN.matcher(s);
     if (!m.find())
         throw new NumberFormatException();
     String num = m.group();
     int inc = Integer.parseInt(num) + 1;
     String incStr = String.format("%0" + num.length() + "d", inc);
     return  m.replaceFirst(incStr);
 }

 @Test
 public static void testIncrementString() {
     System.out.println(increment("ABC123"));  // -> ABC124
     System.out.println(increment("Z00000"));  // -> Z00001
     String url = "https://www.w3resource.com/csharp-exercises/basic/csharp-basic-exercise-3.php";
     System.out.println(increment(url));  // -> https://www.w3resource.com/csharp-exercises/basic/csharp-basic-exercise-3.php
 }
```

Comment: If you know the format of the url and there are known fixed parts to the url then just split the url into strings and if its parameters you are then if its the GET method just look for "?" if its the POST method then the data isn't in the url.  There are also functions like lastIndexOf that would help you locate the last occurance of "-" then move 1 position more to get the position of the 3.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the number is always what immediately precedes the domain, you could take a regex approach to separate the input URL into a first part, coming before the final number, the number itself, and the domain.  Then, iterate in a loop and piece together the URL outputs you want to see.

```
String url = "https://www.w3resource.com/csharp-exercises/basic/csharp-basic-exercise-3.php";
String part1 = url.replaceAll("\\d+\\.[^.]+$", "");
String number = url.replaceAll("^.*(\\d+)\\.[^.]+$", "$1");
String part2 = url.replaceAll("^.*\\d+(\\.[^.]+)$", "$1");
int numStart = Integer.parseInt(number);

for (int i=0; i < 5; ++i) {
    String urlNew = part1 + (numStart + i) + part2;
    System.out.println(urlNew);
}
```

This prints:

```
https://www.w3resource.com/csharp-exercises/basic/csharp-basic-exercise-3.php
https://www.w3resource.com/csharp-exercises/basic/csharp-basic-exercise-4.php
https://www.w3resource.com/csharp-exercises/basic/csharp-basic-exercise-5.php
https://www.w3resource.com/csharp-exercises/basic/csharp-basic-exercise-6.php
https://www.w3resource.com/csharp-exercises/basic/csharp-basic-exercise-7.php
```